# Postgre Admin Window gets stuck in Loading

Tags: pgadmin-4

Whenever I open the pgAdmin 4, it says waiting for start and then a new window opens which shows Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4 but it does not completely loads.

It gets stuck while loading. I have windows environment. I tried killing the task from the task manager and reading FAQs on the EDB (Enterprise Database website), but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Iz tries to connect and can't isz postgres rinning as srtvice?

Comment: I noticed the same thing earlier. It is maybe not the same, but try repositioning/move the program window. It resolved for me.